# Add validation to InputSelect with default placeholder string

Tags: blazor, webassembly, blazor-client-side, asp.net-blazor

I´m using an InputSelect like this:

```
<InputSelect @bind-Value="ExampleName">
    <option>---</option>
    @foreach (var item in itemList)
    {
        <option>@item.Name</option>
    }
</InputSelect>
<ValidationMessage For="@(() => ExampleName)" />
```

The validation is implemented like this:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Custom error message")]
public string ExampleName { get; set; }
```

If I select nothing from the input select, the validation works fine, because ExampleName does not contain anything and thus the `[Required]` attribute isn´t fulfilled. But as soon as I select a valid option, and select the placeholder (---) again, the validation tells me, that the input is valid. Of course it is, because `---` is a string, but I don´t want it to be valid.

How can this option be included as non-valid?

Answer (score 2):

Took me some time, but a simple `value=""` added to the option like this:

```
<option value="">---</option>
```

solves the problem, as the value bound to the InputSelect now only contains an empty string and not the string "---".

Comment: It looks even great if you put the `<option value="">---</option>` on top of a 'optgroup` tag like this.

`<InputSelect class="form-control" @bind-Value="_associationToCreate.SportingCode">
<option value="">---</option>
<optgroup label="Select sporting code">
@foreach (var enumeration in Enumeration.GetAll<SportingCode>())
{
<option value="@enumeration">@enumeration</option>
}
</optgroup>
</InputSelect>`